# Using a gem file in the code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As part of a project, another team have created a gem which we will use, which contains common code.

Now in our gem file we have:

```
gem 'common_code', '0.0.22'
```

Do I need to do anything else to specify how to use this gem?
I need to change some methods in our project which before were like:

```
showMessage(..)
```

to

```
common_code.showMessage(..)
```

ideally would like:

```
cc.showMessage(..)
```

What do I need to do to achieve this?  Still new to rails.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want to use `common_code.showMessage`? Globally? In a Helper/Controller/Model?

Comment: By the way: Camelcase methods look strange in a Ruby environment. Perhaps you should think about switching to underscore notation, which really is the status quo.

Comment: globally I would imagine..

Comment: Note that this is just one example, we will be changing a lot of stuff that has moved into this common gem, which is a rails engine